# How to merge results from next calls of useLazyQuery?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I am trying to get data from api by useLazyQuery on demand:

```
const [getData, { loading, myData }] = useLazyQuery(MY_QUERY);

...

const handleGetData = async (id: string) => { await getData({ variables: { id } }) }
```

The point is that each next call of `getData` with different `id` will not merge results under the same place in the cache. It makes new query with different variables which is understandable but I am trying to merge all result of the `getData`.

Is it possible? Could someone share some solution to achieve that?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. Each individual object will get added to the cache as they get loaded.

Comment: by default running getData will override myData object with next result and I would like to return cached + the one that is returned from network

Comment: Then you'll have to manipulate the cache yourself probably.